# My paragraph won't move up and down;

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my paragraph (#home) move to the middle of the greyed box, but it won't move no matter what. I've tried changing the margin to padding, and making the margin up and down, or even making it ridiculously high, like 1000. Please Help. Here's my code:

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="BrokenRecordNew.css" />
        <title>Broken Record</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="tabsattop">
            <p id="home">Home</p>
            <a href="BrokenRecordNew.html"><img id="logo" src="http://www.freevector.com/site_media/preview_images/FreeVector-Antique-Record-Player.jpg"><a>
        </div> 


    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html { 
    background: url("http://theband.hiof.no/band_pictures/band_mfbp_back.jpg") no-repeat     center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}


#tabsattop{
    background-color: black;
    opacity: .8;
    margin-top:-7px;
    margin-right: -5px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    width: 1274px;
    height: 75px;
}

#logo{
    height: 75px;
    margin-left:550px;
    display:inline-block;
}

#home{
    margin-left: 10px;
    display:inline;
    color:white;
    font-size:25px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: `display: inline` isn't a good option for block level elements like paragraphs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `display:inline`, you've removed the ability to apply `margin` or `padding` to it. Remove `display:inline` (or use `display:inline-block` instead) and you should be good to go.

Comment: Add `vertical-align: top;` to `#home`. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp